# Passing Class object to the method

Tags: java

I have a library method, which returns a collection of Objects by class name.

For example

```
Iterable x = RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext().getObjects(XAgent.class);
```

would return a list of all Objects in Context which are `InstanceOf` XAgent.class

If use it in that way, it work very well. How ever I need a method to pass the class-name to.

```
public Iterable getObjectsFromContext(Class clazz) {
        return RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext().getObjects(clazz);
    }

getObjectsFromContext(XAgent.class);
```

And then it does not work any more, it returns All objects of context... so why it does not pass my "clazz" variable into getObjects() ?

here is the linkt ot javadoc of getObjects();
http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/context/Context.html#getObjects-java.lang.Class-

```
IndexedIterable<T> getObjects(java.lang.Class<?> clazz)
```

update: this works:

```
 public Iterable getObjectsFromContext(Class<?> clazz) {
         return RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext().getObjects(clazz);
    }
    getObjectsFromContext(XAgent.class)
```

Comment: I think you need to provide an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: its actually the MCVE. here is the link to javadoc: http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/context/Context.html#getObjects-java.lang.Class-

Comment: I suspect this isn't the actual code that you call. If it was, it should work. Please try to debug what happens when you call `getObjectsFromContext(XAgent.class)`

Comment: you are right. after debugging I fould that I have output a wrong array

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
public Iterable getObjectsFromContext(Class<?> clazz) {
     return RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext().getObjects(clazz);
}
getObjectsFromContext(XAgent.class)
```

There was a right answer suggested, but I do not see it anymore to accept, that's why I post it on my own.

Answer (score -1):

This won't work because your wrapper function, getObjectsFromContext, explicitly takes in a type of "Class".

Whatever you pass in, it will be interpreted as type "Class" and thus get passed into the getObjects() function as "Class". That will explain why the function returns all objects.

You'll need make your wrapper function generic.

```
public Iterable<T> getObjectsFromContext(T clazz) {
    return RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext().getObjects(clazz);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but so I get an error: The method getObjects(Class) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (T)

Comment: I tried also this code, but then it pass just "Class", so the same result as before.   `public <T> Iterable getObjectsFromContext(Class<T> clazz) {
  return RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext().getObjects(clazz);
 }`

Comment: I think you got it the wrong way around. `getObjects()` does expect a `Class`.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? Is `Class<T> clazz` not a instance of class?

Comment: Hi; Sorry I am actually not familiar with repast, just trying to provide a solution based on what I understand about typing and generics. Sorry it doesn't work, but it looks you got it figured out now.